# How to add array of images to UIImage view programmatically in ios4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage, icarousel

I need to display array of images in a single view which have various effect in icarousel(time machne,coverflow,etc...)i'm going to use single style where all images have to be displayed..
HERE IS MY CODE IN .M FILE..

```
UIImage *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 290, 400)];
NSLog(@"hi");

img.image=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_0.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_1.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_2.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_3.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_4.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_5.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_6.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_7.png"],nil];
```

But its not working...Can anyone help it out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: As per your latest edit, your question entirely changed, hence my answer does not apply.

---

Use `animationImages` instead:

```
UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 290, 400)];
img.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_0.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_1.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_2.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_3.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_4.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_5.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_6.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_7.png"],nil];
```

---

From the [UIImageView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html);

```
animationImages
```

An array of UIImage objects to use for an animation.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *animationImages
```

> Discussion The array must contain UIImage objects. You may use the
>   same image object more than once in the array. Setting this property
>   to a value other than nil hides the image represented by the image
>   property. The value of this property is nil by default.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
See Also
  @property image
  @property contentMode (UIView)
Declared In
UIImageView.h

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
   NSArray *frames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
   [UIImage imageWithName:@"a.png"],
   [UIImage imageWithName:@"b.png"],
   [UIImage imageWithName:@"c.png"],
   [UIImage imageWithName:@"d.png"],
   [UIImage imageWithName:@"e.png"],
   nil];

   UIImageView *animatedIMvw = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
   animatedIMvw.animationImages = frames;
   [animatedIMvw startAnimating];
```

Comment: where is imageWithName: in UIImage?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this simple example: http://appsamuck.com/day2.html

EDIT

It appears that the homepage got broken, so check this out instead:

http://web.archive.org/web/20090207210729/http://appsamuck.com/day2.html